# Call Function in init that waits for properties to initialise

Tags: ios, swift, class, swiftui, combine

I have an Observable Object class to store a forecast object for my app

The class looks like this:

```
final class ForecastData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var forecast: DarkSkyResponse

    public func getForecast(at location: CLLocation) {
        let request = DarkSkyRequest(key: "KEYGOESHERE")
        let point = DarkSkyRequest.Point(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)

        guard let url = request.buildURL(point: point) else {
            //Handle this better
            preconditionFailure("Failed to construct URL")
        }

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
            data, response, error in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard let data = data else {
                    //Handle this better
                    fatalError("No Data Recieved")
                }
                guard let forecast = DarkSkyResponse(data: data) else {
                    //Handle this better
                    fatalError("Decoding Failed")
                }
                self.forecast = forecast
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    init() {
        self.getForecast(at: CLLocation(latitude: 37.334987, longitude: -122.009066))
    }
}
```

The first part simply generates a URL to access the API by. Then I start a `URLSession` which downloads the data and then parses it into a `DarkSkyResponse` object. Finally I set the `@Published` variable to the forecast object.

My problem is when I call the function in the initialiser, I get an error because the forecast property is not initialised. What is the best way to get around this? Where should I call the function?
By the way I am using this class in my SwiftUI View using an `@ObservedObject` property wrapper

Answer (score 1):

Case1: use optional (and you need to handle it in View)

```
@Published var forecast: DarkSkyResponse?
```

Case2: use some default instance

```
@Published var forecast = DarkSkyResponse()
```

Both variants are equivalent and acceptable, so just by your preference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this changes:

```
@Published var forecast: DarkSkyResponse!
```

and

```
init() {
    super.init()
    self.getForecast(at: CLLocation(latitude: 37.334987, longitude: -122.009066))
}
```

Comment: Ah I should probably have mentioned, the problem with force unwrapping the variable is that DarkSkyResponse is full of optionals due to the tricky nature of weather forecasts and how the API can’t guarantee that a property will be present